# Play 2.0 unexpected exception StackOverflowError: null

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When I try to compile my project I get the following exception:

```
! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [StackOverflowError: null]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:233) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:224) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:731) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:4271) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:4138) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:731) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:4271) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$typedApply$1$1.apply(Typers.scala:3353) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
```

I found the same [issue](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/613-stack-overflow-exception-while-trying-to-compile) in the Play 2 issue tracker and they said that when the routes file grows it makes that exception.

Is there a solution to this exception because my project doesn't compile anymore ?

I'm using Play 2.0.3 for scala(my routes file is about 150 line)

Comment: Why not simply set the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable to "-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Xss2m" as suggested in comments on the issue you linked to?

Comment: Well I want to find out if this issue has a fix or not. I will try this workaround as last resort.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to use regular expressions in your route file in order to decrease the number of line ?

Comment: Yeah good idea, but still my routes file will get bigger later and I will face the same problem I think.

Comment: @nico_ekito I think the problem is with the expansion in a Java source file...

Comment: Upgrade Play version. A stackoverflow error was corrected in Play 2.0.4 and 2.0.4 should be backward compatible.

Comment: I upgraded the version to 2.0.4 but the issue is still there. Tried also to set the `_JAVA_OPTIONS`  to `"-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Xss2m"` but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with Play 2.0.6. Upgraded to Play 2.0.8 and it didn't help. I then modified the **$play_dir/framework/build** script so it builds with **-Xss2M** instead of **-Xss1M** and the problem disappeared (I can compile normally now).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with play 2.0 having to do with the size of the routes file, not in terms of the number of routes but rather the physical size of the file (32768 bytes). It seems that this cieling has increased for 2.0.4 and is eliminated with 2.1.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/fZvgWJoCPLc

So, first, I would take a look at the physical size of the routes file. It may be possible cut out comments and/or eliminate commented-out lines. Next, I would try upgrading to version 2.0.4. That is a fairly easy process. You just need to download 2.0.4, point `play` to this new path, and update the /project/plugins.sbt of the project to read:

```
// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")
```

A more long-term fix may be to upgrade your project to 2.1 once it becomes stable.