# Stackoverflow with scala specs2

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0, stack-overflow, specs2

I'm currently writing some unit tests for a play application in scala using the specs2 library.
I constantly have a stack overflow error durring the compilation process.
I've splitted the chain into multiple tests, but some tests are quite huge and the error remains ...
I didn't succeed to change the size of the stack (or the error stay, even if I put a huge value, and modify the system limit).
Anyone got an idea?
Regards,

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451161/play-2-0-unexpected-exception-stackoverflowerror-null

Comment: Can you post a extract of the stack trace during the stackoverflow? I'm interesting in where exactly this occurs. You also write that some tests are huge. In which sense? Lots of expectations? Lots of examples? Then can you describe which system property you changed to increase the stack: the one launching sbt, the one for `javaOptions` in sbt?

Comment: The problem was linked to a too big string.
It's now solved by exporting _JAVA_OPTS="-Xss4M"
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is inherent in the design of specs2. You may want to try ScalaTest. It doesn't have the problem. Short of that you need to increase your stack size. You said you tried that, so either it didn't work or you didn't increase it enough. Not sure how you are compiling, but to get scalac to increase its stack size you could try something like this before compiling:

JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx4096M -Xms256M -Xss20M"
export JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [string interpolation](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/the-latest-release-of-specs2-2.html) and not have any more compilation issues.